# Transform an int result to an option of strings in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that contains these values:

```
ID  Value
1    Mail
2    Portal
3    Terrain
```

And in my program, I want to make a select, so when I pick a number, it shows the 'value' of that number. Something like:

```
SELECT ID as Mail, Portal, Terrain
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Show us some more sample table data and also the expected result.

Comment: The needed table is there... if value is 1, it has to show Mail... this is during the select on my program.
I saw some codes work like.... select ID as (mail, portal, terrain)... but i cant make it work

Comment: Currently, the select shows '1'... and it has to show 'Mail'

Comment: Simply `select id, value from tablename where id = 1`?

Comment: Yeah, thats the easy part... now, it has to show MAIL.. if the number is one... Portal, if its 2... and Terrain if its 3

Comment: But you'll get 'mail' if the number is 1.

Comment: Nope, with your query, it show, 1, 2 or 3

Comment: This question got me blocked cause has a dislike :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when id = 1 then value end) as mail,
       max(case when id = 2 then portal end) as portal,
       max(case when id = 3 then terrain end) as terrain
from ;
```

Comment: Im pretty sure i saw some querys build like... Select ID FROM Table... and if the number is, 1, 2 or 3... it shows a string.

Comment: Gordon, can you help me, someone gave me a dislike here, and now im blocked ;/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're giving the ID by a textbox or something in your program

```
Select Value from TABLE where ID = @ID
```

Comment: It would be better if you wanna do it with an SP